# RCP + JNLP\WebStart App will not start

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, jnlp

I've followed this example: [RCP+JavaWS](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/java_web_start.htm) but the app just briefly comes up and goes away. I've turned the console on and it quickly goes away too. I've tried adding: -console, -consoleLog, and -noExit to my application-desc args and I have searched my Application Data dir to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas where I could look to find the log for this? Or, does anyone know what args I could add to make it log to the console?

Thanks in advance.

Eclipse 3.4
Java 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following jar's and the console now opens and I can see the problems. Hope this helps someone else.

```
org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.2.201.R34x_v20080819.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.1.0.v20080421-2006.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.4.0.v20080421-2006.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20080819.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.2.201.R34x_v20080709.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.4.0.v20080516-0950.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.1.200.v20071203.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.4.1.M20080827-0800a.jar
org.eclipse.ui_3.4.1.M20080910-0800.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the java control panel (on a windows system in system controls) to enable the Java console. This setting can be found on the tab for extended settings. Set the value to show the console. After restarting the application a java icon should appear in the system tray from wich the a console view is accessible.

Comment: I do appreciate you're trying to help, however from the question above: 'I've turned the console on and it quickly goes away too'.